# iOS - download attachment from Gmail using messageId and attachmentId

Tags: ios, gmail-api

I am following Google [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios) documentation in my iOS project where I need to download an attachment from a mail by using it userId, messageId and id [Try out from Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get#try-it).
           Where userId is user's Email address,
                   id is mailId ([Try it.Enter only your EmailId](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it))
                   messageId is which we get by using an one of above id which has an       attachment.

This is so far the code which I am have:

```
- (void)fetchLabels {
    GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersThreadsList];
    [self.service executeQuery:query
                      delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}

- (void)displayResultWithTicket:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket
             finishedWithObject:(GTLGmailListLabelsResponse *)labelsResponse
                          error:(NSError *)error {

    NSDictionary *allIDsDictionaryValue=[labelsResponse.JSON valueForKey:@"threads"];
    NSMutableArray *allIDs=[NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i=0; i<[allIDsDictionaryValue count]; i++) {
        [allIDs addObject:[allIDsDictionaryValue valueForKey:@"id"]];
    }
   NSString *mailID=[[allIDs objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",mailID);//Ex: 14e8af86776e595b 
    //As of now I am using the first id only because it has an attachment.

   // Getting messageId from an id of a mail.
    GTLQueryGmail *query1 = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesGet];
    query1.identifier=mailID;
    [self.service executeQuery:query1
                      delegate:self
             didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicketOfAttachment:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}

- (void)displayResultWithTicketOfAttachment:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket
             finishedWithObject:(GTLGmailListLabelsResponse *)labelsResponse
                          error:(NSError *)error {

    NSDictionary *response1=labelsResponse.JSON;
    NSDictionary *response2=[[[response1 valueForKey:@"payload"] valueForKey:@"parts"]objectAtIndex:1];
    if ([[response2 valueForKey:@"mimeType"] isEqualToString:@"application/vnd.ms-excel"]) {
         attachmentId=[[response2 valueForKey:@"body"]valueForKey:@"attachmentId"];
         NSLog(@"%@",attachmentId); //Ex: ANGjdJ_Uw2o7G2Q16jfC4JSTwD2UIO6LuqDIJZvXFCft0q5ALYuiYfM2gPWG0dcty2n6ZkjnVWekIb_3e2_0TqSpctWNAABsfaSF2x2ktf9uHu63e3eIot_GFA9xgppmaRDyaJEL1V-gIvjfPRxgINK8xM0OuuwnVz2xzcCFckkwpK2XwzZG_QPGPvC2Be2bGKNJI8Ds3hGtqfHYeSWZjOjbsjBuxbUFjf1Mlp0TLol9LLAy2cjGZ_CUBQXzZhhWw9AtNHTU4jwhk4WizKRXbfuDvmRtAy1lPCnTKS6pLg
```

[image: messageId]

```
///Based on id and messageId, I am trying to download the attachment
        GTLQueryGmail *query2 = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesAttachmentsGet];
        query2.identifier=mailID;
        query2.messageId=attachmentId;
        [self.service executeQuery:query2
                          delegate:self
                 didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicketOfDownloadAttachment:finishedWithObject:error:)];
    }else{
        UIAlertView *alertShow=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No Attachment found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertShow show];
    }
}

- (void)displayResultWithTicketOfDownloadAttachment:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket
                         finishedWithObject:(GTLGmailListLabelsResponse *)labelsResponse
                                      error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"response is :%@",labelsResponse.JSON);
     NSLog(@"error is :%@",error);
}

But I am getting error as : Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Invalid attachment token)" UserInfo=0x7b68e740 {error=Invalid attachment token, GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x7b6876e0: {message:"Invalid attachment token" code:400 data:[1]}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Invalid attachment token)}
```

Comment: Can you log `query2`? Would be interesting to see how that looks.

Comment: GTLQueryGmail *query2 = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesAttachmentsGet];
        NSLog(@"first log:%@",query2);
        query2.identifier=mailID;
        query2.messageId=attachmentId;
        NSLog(@"second log:%@",query2);

Comment: first log:GTLQueryGmail 0x7994bd20: {method:gmail.users.messages.attachments.get}
 second log:GTLQueryGmail 0x7994bd20: {method:gmail.users.messages.attachments.get params:(id,messageId)}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the Ids mixed up a bit.

```
GTLQueryGmail *query2 = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersMessagesAttachmentsGet];
        query2.id=attachmentId;
        query2.messageId=mailID;
```

The data you get in your response is [Base64-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and has been made URL safe by replacing all "+" with "-", and all "/" with "_".

Simply convert it back to regular Base64-data and decode it! Try this in your Developer Tools (press F12):

```
atob("SGV5IE5pbGVzaCEgSSBob3BlIHlvdSB3aWxsIGdldCBpdCB0byB3b3JrIHNvb24h".replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/\_/g, '/'));
```

Do the same steps in your code and you will have your data in its original format.

Comment: That's Cool Buddy.....because of naming convention I was confused that where I am getting wrong......thanks a lot once again :)

Comment: No problem Nilesh! Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Hi Tholle......Can you please suggest me what to do from here now after getting "data".

Comment: @NileshKumar Edited the response.

Comment: Hi Need some more help on this topic.

Comment: @NileshKumar Create a new question, and I will try to help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248969/ios-gmail-api-downloading-the-original-file-i-e-the-attachment-after-getting-at