# Converting attachment data string from Gmail API to Data always returns nil on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, gmail-api, nsdata

I've been using this SO post ([iOS - download attachment from Gmail using messageId and attachmentId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578715/ios-download-attachment-from-gmail-using-messageid-and-attachmentid)) as a reference for

I've been able to make the API call, get the response data and parse out the data for the attachment:

```
            AF.request("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/\(email.id)/attachments/\(email.payload.body.attachmentId)", headers: headers)
                .responseJSON
                
                { [self] response in
                  
                    do {
                        let json = try JSON(data: response.data!)
                        
                        let jsonDict = convertToDictionary(text: json.rawString()!)
                        let attachmentDataString: String? = jsonDict!["data"] as? String
```

Following the accepted answer in the linked post, I made sure to format my string so that it was base64 compatible:

```
let formattedString = attachmentDataString!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

And then attempt to convert that string to data:

```
let attachmentData = Data(base64Encoded: formattedString)
```

However, this object is always nil (I'm pre-checking to make sure I only run this logic on emails with attachments).

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: This is the data string before my formatting:

https://gist.github.com/narner/d7805807992fa44a30e00d6480a04164

And this is the data string after my formatting:

https://gist.github.com/narner/02c3152d1dc935985a4da8d9b7388ade

Comment: Show your formattedString. it is probably not a valid base64 string

Comment: @LeoDabus updated with gists of the string!